# Conditional probability given only the converse conditional probability, and the average of one variable

Tags: self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability, expected-value

I’ve been working on this question for a few days now. Full disclosure: this is from a homework problem set.

This is one of the exercises of Barnett's book on [quantum information](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282320/pnn-given-pnn-and-overline-n).

A particle counter records counts with an efficiency $\eta$. This means that each particle is detected with probability $\eta$ and missed with probability $1-\eta$. Let $N$ be the number of particles present and $n$ be  the number of detected. 
Then:
\begin{equation}
P(n|N)=\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}\eta^n (1-\eta)^{N-n}
\end{equation}

I know the mean number of particle present is:

\begin{equation}
\bar{N}=\sum N P(N)
\end{equation}

I know that I’m supposed to use Bayes’ Theorem, but I don’t see how I’m supposed to use the fact that $\bar{N}$ is known. Every effort so far has yielded an unwieldy fraction that can’t be simplified.

For completeness, here is a screenshot of the question in question:

[image]

Comment: I first thought you were confusing the observed average $\bar{N}$ with the expectation $\mathbb{E}[N]$ but $N$ being the unknown parameter, I have trouble understanding questions (b): is there an upper bound on $N$? and question (c): is this a hidden attempt at running maximum entropy?